# After recursion call the next printf automatically prints the incremented values

Tags: c, recursion

I came across the strange thing in recursion, please go through the below code in printing numbers in descending order.But sooner it completes recursion and executes next printf statement it increments automatically without increment statement in the program.

```
int main()
{
    int count=10;    
    counter(count);    
}

int counter(int count)    
{    
    if(count>0)    
    { 
        printf("%d\n",count);   
        counter(count-1);    
        printf("%d",count) //THIS STATMENT MAKES THE VALUE INCREMENT    
        //AFTER THE RECURSION    
    }    
}
```

output:

```
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
1  //2nd printf results in increment without any increment operator 
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Comment: I suggest you step through the code in a debugger, you don't even need to step into the recursions, just step through the first call call and it should become clear why the variable is "increasing".

Comment: @ Nandu remove that second `printf` because its recursion first printf printed first then recursion starts unitl count>0 becomes false, then it starts to print count values which is printed by second printf , ultimately first printf print decremented values. becuse recursion decrements values after it finishes it prints last printf statement in increment order in reverse order. hope this helps

Comment: I think `count` is not incrementing , last `printf` just prints the value of `count` which was in previous call .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call

```
counter(count-1);
```

the new invocation of the function is called with the value of `counter-1` but the value of `counter` in the current invocation of the function does not change. Hence, when the function returns, the next call to `printf` prints the value of `counter`.

If you visualize the call when `count` is 2, you get

```
printf("%d\n",2);   
counter(1);    
printf("%d\n",2);  // I am assuming you have \n there.
```

If you expand the call to `counter(1)`, you get:

```
printf("%d\n",2);
  printf("%d\n",1);
  counter(0);
  printf("%d\n",1);
printf("%d\n",2);
```

`counter(0)` does not print anything. It returns without doing anything. Hence, that block of code is equivalent to:

```
printf("%d\n",2);
  printf("%d\n",1);
  printf("%d\n",1);
printf("%d\n",2);
```

If you start from a higher number, like 10, you get:

```
printf("%d\n",10);
  printf("%d\n",9);

     ...

         printf("%d\n",2);
           printf("%d\n",1);
           printf("%d\n",1);
         printf("%d\n",2);

     ...

  printf("%d\n",9);
printf("%d\n",10);
```

That explains the output.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is not accurate to explain the answer.
It will still increase the after you change the value counter directly

```
int main()
{
   int count=10;    
   counter(count);    
}

int counter(int count)    
{    
  if(count>0)    
  {  
    count = count-1
    printf("%d\n",count);   
    counter(count);    
    printf("%d",count) //THIS STATMENT MAKES THE VALUE INCREMENT    
    //AFTER THE RECURSION    
  }    
}
```

above code will still make some same output with a little changing